# Error "illegal start of expression" en NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, interfaz-gráfica

estoy programando una aplicacion y me tira el error "illegal start of expression", por lo que deduzco que debe ser un error de escritura pero no lo encuentro. Aca abajo dejo el segmento del codigo que me causa este error:

```
`public static void main(string args[]){
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        new ventanauno().setVisible(true);
    });
```

Comment: el string no deberia ser "String" ?

Comment: el ` no esta en el codigo, fue un error de tipeo al postear la pregunta, y puse String con la S mayuscula y sigue apareciendome ese error

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podes usar el boton [edit] y modificar tu pregunta de ser necesario

Answer (score 1):

Intenta cambiando

```
main(string args[])
```

Por:

```
main(String args[])
```

En java, la clase `String` es con `S` mayuscula al principio.

Comment: Con respecto a la pregunta, aplica cierre por el siguiente motivo: "Parece ser un problema que contiene errores tipográficos."